# AWS RDS with node js : ERROR: Unexpected key 'DeleteProtection' found in params

Tags: node.js, amazon-rds, aws-sdk-js

I have created an AWS RDS instance and am now trying to modify a parameter `DeletionProtection` to **Enabled** from a node.js script.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#modifyDBInstance-property
After checking the content in above link, I have tried to implement something like below:

```
         var params = {
             DBInstanceIdentifier: <db name>,
             DeletionProtection: true,
             ApplyImmediately: true
         };

         var dbDeleteProtect = rds.modifyDBInstance(params).promise();
         dbDeleteProtect
             .then(function (rsp) {
                 console.log(rsp);

             })
             .catch(function (err) {
                 console.log("Error updating DB Deletion protection"+err);             

             });
```

The above returns error like `Unexpected key 'DeletionProtection' found in params`

I am using the API Version: **2014-10-31** and AWS-SDK used is **aws-sdk-2.4.12.min.js**.

Can someone suggest what can be done?

Just thought it might be helpful to share some more info:
When I add *MultiAZ* parameter as below, the same code is working fine. So I am assuming this could be some issue with AWS-SDK that I am using(not sure about this)

```
var params = {
                 DBInstanceIdentifier: <db name>,
                 MultiAZ: true, //works fine with this parameter
                 ApplyImmediately: true
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mistyped the property name, it should be `DeletionProtection` instead of `DeleteProtection` according to AWS docs.

Comment: Even when DeletionProtection is used I was getting the same error and this was my first approach also. Then I started trying with DeleteProtection, DeletionProtect and so on.

Error updating DB Deletion protectionUnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'DeletionProtection' found in params

Comment: Weird. Don't see the code that is setting the API Version. Perhaps double check that you are indeed using `2014-10-31` just before you are running `modifyDBInstance`?

Comment: RE your edits: `MultiAZ` is available in even older API versions. This leads me to believe that indeed you might be using an older version then you think you are.

Comment: rds = new aws.RDS({apiVersion: '2014-10-31'});
I guess I am using the latest API version.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the AWS-SDK being used.
The option DeletionProtection is introduced early in 2018, but the revision aws-sdk-2.4.12 was released much before that. So DeletionProtection is not supported by the SDK itself.

I have downloaded latest version of SDK and re-executed the code and the code works fine. Now DeletionProtection  parameter change is updated for AWS-RDS instances.